# AWS Glue - Spark Job - how to increase Memory Limit or run more efficiently?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, aws-glue, pyspark

While running Spark (Glue) job - during writing of Dataframe to S3 - getting error:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used.
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or 
disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

Is there an easy cure for this?

How writing of Dataframe to S3 can be optimized (to use less memory)?

How memory can be increased for containers so that they we have more room to work with?

Comment: The solution is already suggested on the error message. Disable vmem check.

Comment: you have to increase number of DPUs or have to raise AWS support ticket if you have support available to increase DPUs memory soft limit.

Comment: How to Disable vmem check?

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know, AWS Glue jobs doesn't support increasing memory. But you can select G1.X as worker type for the Glue job. AWS recommends to use this for memory intensive work loads. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html

Apart from that, I don't see any configuration option to increase the memory.

Did you check the memory profile of job runtime metrics?

Comment: How to check memory profile of job runtime metrics?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-glue-job-cloudwatch-metrics.html